# Creating a View from Multiple tables without Duplicating Output

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to a create a view from 3 different tables and not have duplicate output. My current code I have seems to organise book titles to subjects correctly. However, it prints every book title to the same author and when it's done it'll move onto the next author. Instead of having 15 Rows it end ups being 270.

```
CREATE VIEW book_summary(author_first_name, author_last_name, book_title, subject)
AS SELECT  DISTINCT first_name, last_name,title, subject
FROM authors, books  left join subjects
ON subjects.subject_id = books.subject_id;
```

I've tried going through SOF to find the answer. In which I came across DISTINCT and LEFT JOIN from [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686925/data-from-two-tables-without-repeating-data-from-the-first). I just don't think I'm using it correctly

```
Output:
Andrew            | Brookins         | 2001: A Space Odyssey       | Science Fiction
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Bartholomew and the Oobleck | Children's Books
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Dune                        | Science Fiction
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Dynamic Anatomy             | Arts
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Franklin in the Dark        | Children's Books
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Goodnight Moon              | Children's Books
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Learning Python             | Computers
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Little Women                | Drama
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Perl Cookbook               | Computers
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Practical PostgreSQL        | Computers
 Andrew            | Brookins         | Programming Python          | Computers
 Andrew            | Brookins         | The Cat in the Hat          | Children's Books
 Andrew            | Brookins         | The Shining                 | Horror
 Andrew            | Brookins         | The Tell-Tale Heart         | Horror
 Andrew            | Brookins         | The Velveteen Rabbit        | Classics
```

(continues this trend for every author I have in the other table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you use `CROSS JOIN/comma syntax`:

```
CREATE VIEW book_summary
   (author_first_name, author_last_name, book_title, subject)
AS 
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name,title, subject
FROM authors, books  --here is the problem
left join subjects  
ON subjects.subject_id = books.subject_id;
```

It should be rather:

```
CREATE VIEW book_summary
   (author_first_name, author_last_name, book_title, subject)
AS 
SELECT first_name, last_name,title, subject
FROM authors a 
JOIN books b
  ON a.col_name = b.col_name
left join subjects s 
ON s.subject_id = b.subject_id;
```